# How to transform select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have DDL:

```
drop table names
drop table salary

create table names(
id int, 
name1 varchar(50),
char1 varchar(50),
char2 varchar(50))

insert into names values (1,'name1','char1','chara'),
                         (2,'name2','char2','charb'),
                         (3,'name3','char3','charc'),
                         (4,'name4','char4','chard'),
                         (5,'name5','char5','charf');

create table salary(
id int, 
salary int,
bonus int,
oldsalary int)

insert into salary values (1,500,245,354),
                         (2,600,345,246),
                         (3,60,365,334),
                         (4,55,545,364),
                         (5,25,345,374);
```

And have the many SQL query' s (one of them)

```
    SELECT n.name1,
       s.salary,
       s.bonus,
       ( s.bonus + s.salary ) AS Sumsalary
FROM   names n
       INNER JOIN salary s
               ON n.id = s.id
```

I want to write select query that retrieves all fieldnames from tables that used in SQL query divided by usage in this select query with some additional info mentioned in screenshot.

**Format of data that I want retrieve from this query**:[image: **enter image description here]

Comment: Interesting, but not easy. What with queries that depends on complicated `VIEW/TABLE FUNCTION` or queries with many subqueries. Second column `Used in Query` for expression like `(s.bonus + s.salary) as Sumsalary`. How would you tell Table name for `CONCAT(n.name1, s.salary) as col`? Anyway for starting point you can use [**dm_exec_describe_first_result_set**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406815)

Comment: Name it "col" and include name1,salary in fieldnames with flag 0.  Mark used in Query 1 only if used simple field without calculations

Comment: And tableName for computed column?

Comment: The best variant it is tables divided by /. But for simplification it will be ok if we make first table

Comment: This can be achieved but it will involve a lot of dynamic-SQL + checking metatadata in system tables. But I doubt you will be able to handle corner cases.

Comment: In corner case's We can make simplifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the list of tables & columns for queries if you have access to the system views:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' AS ns)
SELECT DISTINCT st.TEXT AS QueryText, 
                C.value('./@Table', 'varchar(50)') As Tab,
                C.value('./@Column', 'varchar(50)') As Col
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st
CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('//ns:ColumnReference') as T(C)
WHERE cp.ObjType = 'Adhoc' AND
      St.Text Like '%s.bonus%' AND
      st.Text Not Like '%WITH XMLNAMESPACES%' AND 
      C.value('./@Table', 'varchar(50)') IS NOT NULL
```

This gives the following results:

```
QueryText            Tab       Col
SELECT n.name1, ...  [Names]   id
SELECT n.name1, ...  [Names]   name1
SELECT n.name1, ...  [Salary]  bonus
SELECT n.name1, ...  [Salary]  id
SELECT n.name1, ...  [Salary]  salary
```

You could then use these results as a means of linking to `sys.columns` to determine which coulmns are missing etc.